# Sort an integer array by given starting integer

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

I have an array:

```
int[] months = new int[4] {1, 4, 7, 10};
```

I would like to sort the array starting by the given value and sort the rest of the array in the original order.

Let's say I want to start sorting the array by a value of `7`. The sorted array would be then in order of:

```
7, 10, 1, 4
```

Or starting with a value `4` the sorted array would be an order of
`4, 7, 10, 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
var orderedMonths = months.Where(x => x >= 7)
                          .OrderBy(x => x)
                          .Concat(months.Where(x => x < 7));
```

Note that this will mean that the elements of the "rest of the array" will be in order of appearance rather than increasing numeric order. If you meant the latter (i.e. sort both 'segments' numerically) , I would do:

```
var orderedMonths = months.OrderBy(x => x < 7) // false comes before true
                          .ThenBy(x => x);
```

On the other hand, if you want to sort both segments by order of appearance, I would do:

```
var orderedMonths = months.GroupBy(x => x < 7)
                          .OrderBy(group => group)
                          .SelectMany(x => x);
```

(or)

```
var orderedMonths = months.Where(x => x >= 7)
                          .Concat(months.Where(x => x < 7));
```

Comment: You can use .Where and .OrderBy with lambda values on an array?

Comment: @TravisJ: Sure, an `int[]` is an `IEnumerable<int>`. The compiler will then use the LINQ to Objects extension-methods on `IEnumerable<T>` in the `Enumerable` class.

Comment: @Ani: sems to me that the algorithm is not correct, cause if you look on specification provided by OP, you will see that the sort is not done by `value` provided, but by `index` of that value in array. In other words selecting something by `>=7` is not correct.

Comment: @Tigran: It's really not clear either way because the provided array is already sorted. I understand what you mean though. Let's wait for clarification from the OP. :)

Comment: @Ani Oh cool, I didn't know that :) I thought those operators were only available for modeled objects, but it makes sense that they would apply to all objects which were Enumerable.

Comment: var orderedMonths = months.Where(x => x >= 7).Concat(months.Where(x => x < 7)); I can now use it like this: var orderedMonths = months.Where(x => x >= DateTime.Now.Month).Concat(months.Where(x => x < DateTime.Now.Month)); This solved the problem.

Comment: +1 for providing different solutions to meet the incomplete requirements. :P

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your sorted int array you could

```
int[] months = new int[4] { 1, 4, 7, 10 };
int value = 10; 
int[] chk1 = new int[4];
chk1 = months.SkipWhile(a => a != value).
                Concat(months.TakeWhile(a => a != value)).ToArray();
```

This should get you the required order

Comment: Going to be hard to do this if the array needs to be dynamic though, as far as making chk1 goes.

Comment: Ah, I am not near a compiler and wasn't sure how strict the restrictions on initiating arrays were.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a list?

```
int NumberToBeFound = 7;
int IndexOfNumber = -1;
for(int i=0;i<months.count;i++){
  if(months[i] == NumberToBeFound){
    IndexOfNumber = i;
    break;
  }
}
List<int> Sorted = new List<int>();
for(int i = IndexOfNumber; i < months.count;i++){
  Sorted.Add(months[i]);
}
for(int i = 0; i < IndexOfNumber; i++){
  Sorted.Add(months[i]);
}
months = Sorted.ToArray();
```